# How can I let my users set PHP.ini settings for wordpress?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, wordpress

I set up a wordpress server from a fairly standard Ubuntu 9.10 for a class and they're constantly running into problems with the default PHP.ini settings. First memory settings were too low, then the file upload limits were too small, etc. And more concerning was a wordpress wide blank page that I suspect was killed for ram consumption but turning on php errors in php.ini didn't reveal anything!

I'm not familiar with shared hosting, but I feel there's a way such places allow users to edit such things without needing me to intervene and restart Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can't fix the php.ini file while it's running (iirc it's only read when apache starts), but your don't actually have to change it to make your changes.

[ini-set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) allows you to change the option within the code. It's a bit tedious to set one option at a time, so they added [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to...well, parse an .ini file.

You can also over-ride the values with an .htaccess file, using the [php_flag](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) directive.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to let your users touch PHP.ini settings (particularly since this requires `AllowOverride Options` or `AllowOverride All` to be set, which can open up a lot of ways for your users to create security holes.

When I was doing the ISP/Shared Hosting thing I set relatively generous system-wide limits and users who routinely hit those limits could **buy** a higher class of service (at which point I or someone from the admin team would edit the Apache configuration for their specific virtual host & increase their limits).

This has two major advantages: Security (Your users can't glom all your memory or upload some obscenely large file and fill your disk) and Cash Flow (Users taking a greater share of resources are forced to pay for them), and the additional demands on your time are relatively minimal.  As a bonus you also know what resources you're committing, so you know if you're over-committing the server to a point where you may need to bring up a new one and migrate some clients.

Comment: I appreciate the market oriented solution, but we're within the same firm (yay Coase's theorem).

Comment: I would still have visceral objections to allowing users to set PHP options via .htaccess -- it only takes one user deciding that a sledgehammer is better than a scalpel & you wind up with all sorts of issues (and as the admin it's obviously *your* fault :).  That said since it's in the same organization the `AllowOverride` directive or loosening up restrictions so you can implement Satanicpuppy's suggestion aren't quite so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Run 'em via FastCGI so you can keep everything isolated to their own UID (suPHP/suExec). Then, provide a php wrapper that loads a custom ini file. That will let them edit their own settings, but keep everything constrained to their own UID. I've got a handful of Wordpress installs working like this (though I also set memory limits per-user).